# How to move multiple shapes together WITHOUT using Group

Tags: kineticjs

I am new to KineticJS and have a very basic question.

I am trying to create a graph (parent-child hierarchy) using KineticJS. So in any node I will have 3 things:

1) A circle as the node itself

2) a small image of '+' sign attached to the circle. Clicking this '+' will allow creation 
of child node.

3) a line connecting this node with the child node.

I tried bundling all 3 of them in a 'Group' but the problem is all 3 of them move together when I drag the group - which is obviously expected - but its a problem when I drag the child node it "detaches" the line connecting to the parent node.

Basically only one end of the line which is connected to the child node should move and the end connected to parent should be fixed.

How do I acheive this? A quick code snippet will help me deal with this problem which I am trying to solve in vain for past 2 days.

Thanks so much!

-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can keep your parent and child nodes connected by creating a line with a custom drawFunc.**

The line’s custom drawFunc just gets the parent & child positions and draws itself between them.

```
drawFunc: function(canvas){
    var ctx=canvas.getContext();
    var x1=parentNode.getPosition().x;
    var y1=parentNode.getPosition().y;
    var x2=childNode.getPosition().x;
    var y2=childNode.getPosition().y;
    ctx.save();
    ctx.strokeStyle="red";
    ctx.lineWidth=3;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
},
```

You might also want to keep the line drawn behind the nodes rather than on top.

Your can do this by setting the stage.getDragLayer.afterDraw function to move the connecting line to the bottom of the z-index

```
stage.getDragLayer().afterDraw(function() {
    connector.moveToBottom();
    layer.draw();
});
```

Here is code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/tt2KG/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Prototype</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.3.3-beta.js"></script>

<style>
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){


    function init(){

        var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
            container: 'container',
            width: 400,
            height: 400
        });
        var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
        stage.add(layer);

        var parentNode = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: 50,
          y: 80,
          radius: 40,
          fill: "blue",
          stroke: "red",
          strokeWidth: 3,
          draggable: true
        });    

        var childNode = new Kinetic.Circle({
          x: 150,
          y: 80,
          radius:25,
          fill: "green",
          stroke: "red",
          strokeWidth: 3,
          draggable: true
        });    

        var connector = new Kinetic.Line({
            drawFunc: function(canvas){
                var ctx=canvas.getContext();
                var x1=parentNode.getPosition().x;
                var y1=parentNode.getPosition().y;
                var x2=childNode.getPosition().x;
                var y2=childNode.getPosition().y;
                ctx.save();
                ctx.strokeStyle="red";
                ctx.lineWidth=3;
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(x1,y1);
                ctx.lineTo(x2,y2);
                ctx.stroke();
                ctx.restore();
            },
            points: [1,1,1,3],
            stroke: "red",
            strokeWidth: 2,
            lineCap: 'round',
            lineJoin: 'round',
            opacity: 1,
            draggable:false
        });
        layer.add(connector);
        layer.add(parentNode);
        layer.add(childNode);

        // keep connector on rect1+rect2
        stage.getDragLayer().afterDraw(function() {
            connector.moveToBottom();
            layer.draw();
        });

        layer.draw();
    }

init();

}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```